# How to put the text in the center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

how to put the text in the center carousel (bootstrap).Try to adjust the span element or?

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <span><strong><p>Aktuelnosti u proizvodnji malina</p></strong>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: span
{ color:grey; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size: 50px;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.carousel-caption {
text-align: center;
}
```

This will Center any text contained in the div. if you just want to do the span you can use

```
.carousel-caption span {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 2.3 has class text-center ,http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html

for the below versions you can add the css class for the tags elements and use it

```
.text-center{
   text-align: center !important;
  }

 <p class="text-center">
```